# Is it possible to change price of ready invoice in Magento PHP

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Is it possible to change price of ready invoice in Magento trough PHP.
I'm using M2E but sometimes I've got strange item price so I have to manually edit that trough phpMyAdmin so now I'm looking for some code example how to change the price of item for already submitted invoice.

If I can't find any magento ready functions for price change I should use direct mySQL query which I don't prefer.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.